# Build multi module java maven project

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to maven and tried to set it up on a web project that contains several modules!
But I am facing a little problem and I don't see how to solve it!

So I have :

```
MonEar
 |_ Module_db1
 |_ Module_db2
 |_ Module_war
```

and

```
<artifactId>Module_db1</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Module_db1</name>
<parent>
    <groupId>MonAppMultiModule</groupId>
    <artifactId>app.multi.module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

in the parent pom:
XML code:

```
    <modules>
    <module>Module_db1</module>
    <module>Module_db2</module>
    <module>Module_war</module>
    <module>MonEar</module>
</modules>
```

there is surely something that I did not understand but I do not see what!
Could someone enlighten me?

thank you in advance

Edit: I forgot to specify that I had added the Module_db1 and Module_db dependencies in the Module_war pom.
As follows :
XML code:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>Module_db1</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>Module_db1</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is your question?